# Java How to convert time literal to long value?

Tags: java, date

If I have a time (String) coming into my class with the following format

```
2013-01-25T07:31:51.00Z
```

How do i turn that into a long?

I don't even know what format that is to put in to a DateFormat. Anyone else have a clue?

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
```

Desired results

```
long time = changeMe("2013-01-25T07:31:51.00Z");

System.out.print(time);

//012432423  <-- But only the actual long
```

Comment: Why would you want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the excellent [jodatime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
long time = fmt.parseDateTime("2013-01-25T07:31:51.00Z").getMillis();
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you have [iso8601](/questions/tagged/iso8601) format here. Try this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public long changeMe(String isoTimestamp) {
  final Calendar c = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(isoTimestamp);
  return c.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

BTW `c.getTime()` returns `Date` object, if you prefer.

## See also:

- [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925)

Comment: Thank you greatly! I was completely baffled to what format this was.